# CSS border styling

Tags: html, css

I have a problem regarding my CSS, I have a `<table>` which I put border when I put CSS in it which is like this

```
table, th, td, tr {
    border: thin 1px solid black;
}
```

I got double solid line which look like this

[image]

What I need is a table that doesn't have spaces in between. How can I do that in CSS? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```